# how to consume rabbitmq queue using Gatling?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am using Gatling 3.3.1 and Scala 2.12.10,
I am able to publish the message with this code

```
val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("AMQP test")
.feed(idFeeder)
.exec(
  amqp("publish to exchange").publish
    .queueExchange("test_q_in")
    .textMessage("Hello message - ${id}")
    .messageId("${id}")
    .priority(0)
)
```

Now I want to consume it in another queue with the separate request, so I can show publish and consume both results in the report.

I tried this with older version 2.2.0-M3 which works fine. I want to do same with 3.3.1

```
val scn  = scenario("Performance Test").repeat(1) {
 exec(
   amqp("Publish Message").publish("request")
  )
 .exec {
  amqp("Consume Result")
  .consume("result", autoAck = true)
}
```

Comment: Gatling doesn't have an official AMQP support. You're using some community plugin, probably actually multiple ones for Gatling 2 (dead for years) and Gatling 3. Anything can happen. You probably should reach out to the authors of those plugins, directly on their GitHub project.

Comment: So I can not use Gatling for this testing?

Comment: I said: reach out to the authors of those community plugins, directly on their GitHub project.